# How to automatically format NOW() in to a string that that displays YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to format the output of NOW() to a string that displays `YYYY-MM-DD`?

This is the output of NOW(): `29/02/2012 12.07.37`

The reason is, that I need to use the current date in a QUERY.

QUERY only accepts date in the format YYYY-MM-DD . I can't get a date directly from a cell, because it gets formatted as (even if I change the formatting): `DD/MM/YYYY`

Perhaps some regular expression?

Comment: You will need to say more about what you are doing. There are a number of different ways to format a date, and there is a Date() function, similar to Now(), but without time. Not all functions are acceptable in queries, so what you use will depend on where and how you are running the query.

Comment: Do you just want a string?  Have you tried: `Format(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")`?

Comment: @TonyDallimore: I think your comment is worth an answer

Comment: @JMax.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I made it a comment because it seems too obvious.  I assumed I was missing the true purpose of the question.  But what is "obvious"?  I think I know Excel quite well but I learn something almost everyday from a answer on this site.  The authors of those answers probably thought they were writing something obvious.  Even the people I admire the most (such as yourself) are sometimes forced to admit they had learnt something.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: this is very true. We **all** learn every day something new (see [Daniel's post about it](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106661248019508703534/posts/EKVsiHK55cB)). Even if it seemed obvious to us, this can be something new to the OP. Moreover, you detailed your answer and your explanation was really worth it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is supposed to be an in-cell formula then you can use

`=TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: This is giving an #ERROR

Comment: @HappyBird Do oyu have a typo somewhere? It still works in Excel for me.

Comment: @Brad I see, it works in Excel. I thought this answer was for google spreadsheets given the tags used by the thread creator.

Comment: @HappyBird you're right but it works in Google Sheets too. https://imgur.com/tzLDieg

Answer (score 3):

I will follow JMax's suggestion and convert my comment to an answer.

`Now()` returns the current date and time as a number.  The integer part gives the date and the fraction part gives the time.  If you print or display that date, the default is to give the full date in what Microsoft think's is the local format.

`Format(expn, fmt)` allows you to convert an expression to a string.  For example:

```
Dim DateStg as String

DateStg = Format(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

`fmt` defines the format to which the `expn` is to be converted.  `fmt` is a mixture of code letters (such as: "yyyy", "mm", "dd") and punctuation (such as "-").  "yyyy-mm-dd" appears to meet your current needs but you can also usethe following to format dates:

- "mmm" to give three letter month (Jan, Feb, etc.)
- "mmmm" to give full name of month (January, February, etc)
- "ddd" to give three letter day of week (Mon, Tue, etc)
- "dddd" to give full name of day of week (Monday, Tuesday, etc)

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net you can do the following:

```
Dim dateStr As String = Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

In C# you can do it like this:

```
String  dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: I think the OP was rather looking for some VBA (as he tagged his question with `Excel`) but I upvoted your answer to encourage you answering other questions and contribute to SO.